# best way to loop an array

Tags: programming-languages

```
var data = [];

for (i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {

for (i = 0, i < data.length; i++) {
```

`What is the difference between these two way of forming an loop` and `which is sited as best among them.`

**`Calling the first one is cheaper than the second one. Is it true?`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is - according to:

http://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a

Note: you could easily build a test if you are not convinced.

Comment: Note that this is for JavaScript only, in most other languages I doubt it matters as much. Also, this benchmark was made in 2008 with Firefox 3.0.1 - modern compilers have much better, highly optimized JavaScript engines.

Comment: I agree. Also, I myself prefer to optimize for readability (= less bugs) than performance, unless there is a good reason for performance optimizations (and there should be negligable difference it this case). So basically I would always choose the 2nd way.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you'll have an additional `len` variable the holds `data.length`. You can do this if you need the value of `data.length` again inside the for loop (f.e. if retrieving it is computionally expensive).

But note that it is the same as

```
len = data.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

which I'd prefer for readability.

Comment: Calling the first one is cheaper than the second one. Is it true?

Comment: As I said, depends if you'll need `data.length` inside the for loop again. If not, the second is a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depends of the language. Most compilers will see length to be a loop invariant and move it outside itself. This kind of details are of little importance, the real important thing in loop is to have loops that are cache friendly , ie go down your data in a way cache spatial and temporal locality is maximal.